# Can't reshape (pivot) pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, reshape

So I have this DF:

```
In [130]: dfAbr
Out[130]: 
           ip ospfArea router_name
0     1.1.1.1  0.0.0.2   Router1-1
1     1.1.1.2  0.0.0.2   Router1-2
140   5.5.5.1  0.0.0.5   Router5-1
141   5.5.5.2  0.0.0.5   Router5-2
```

I'd like to reshape that into a 2-row dataframe, such as:

[image]

I've been playing with both `stack/unstack` and `pivot`  functions but couldn't go that far.

For example, `dfAbr1 = pd.DataFrame(dfAbr.set_index('ospfArea').stack()).reset_index()`, renaming column names, produces the following:

```
In [151]: dfAbr1
Out[151]: 
  ospfArea       level1     level2
0  0.0.0.2           ip    1.1.1.1
1  0.0.0.2  router_name  Router1-1
2  0.0.0.2           ip    1.1.1.2
3  0.0.0.2  router_name  Router1-2
4  0.0.0.5           ip    5.5.5.1
5  0.0.0.5  router_name  Router5-1
6  0.0.0.5           ip    5.5.5.2
7  0.0.0.5  router_name  Router5-2
```

From there, I wanted to `pivot` it, like this: `dfAbr1.pivot(index='ospfArea', columns='level1',values='level2')`, but couln't do it as I get `Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`. I believe this is because under `level1` I have duplicate values...

Any other way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution with pivot, also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

```
new_df = (df.assign(col=df.groupby('ospfArea').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='ospfArea', columns='col')
)

new_df.columns = [f'{x[0]}{x[1]+1}' for x in new_df.columns]
```

Output:

```
              ip1      ip2 router_name1 router_name2
ospfArea                                            
0.0.0.2   1.1.1.1  1.1.1.2    Router1-1    Router1-2
0.0.0.5   5.5.5.1  5.5.5.2    Router5-1    Router5-2
```

Comment: I liked your idea. One comment though: I did `df['col'] = df.groupby('ospfArea').cumcount()` ... why did you use `assign` instead?

Comment: It's just easier to chain (and does not alter your original data).

Answer (score 8):

Create `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with counter column by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and flatten `Multiindex` by `map` with `format`:

```
df = df.set_index(['ospfArea', df.groupby('ospfArea').cumcount().add(1)]).unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format)
print (df)
              ip1      ip2 router_name1 router_name2
ospfArea                                            
0.0.0.2   1.1.1.1  1.1.1.2    Router1-1    Router1-2
0.0.0.5   5.5.5.1  5.5.5.2    Router5-1    Router5-2
```